# How to hook into access control of node/add menu handler?

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks

Looking at Drupal code, I noticed the following function.

```
function _node_add_access() {
  $types = node_type_get_types();
  foreach ($types as $type) {
    if (node_hook($type->type, 'form') && node_access('create', $type->type)) {
      return TRUE;
    }
  }
  if (user_access('administer content types')) {
    // There are no content types defined that the user has permission to create,
    // but the user does have the permission to administer the content types, so
    // grant them access to the page anyway.
    return TRUE;
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

What is `node_hook()`? How can I implement this hook for additional access control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`node_hook()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_hook/7) is not an hook; it's a helper function Drupal uses to verify a content-type hook exists. In the code you are showing, the function is verifying the module implementing the `$type->type` content type implements [`hook_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_form/7).

To alter the access control for a node, you have two options:

- Implementing [`hook_node_access()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7)
- Implementing [`hook_node_grants()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_grants/7) and [`hook_node_access_records()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_access_records/7)

Implementing `hook_node_access()` is easier, but that hook is not used in node listings (lists of nodes generated from a select query, such as the default home page at path 'node', an RSS feed, a recent content block, etc.).

Notice that, since `_node_add_access()` is an access callback, you could change the access callback used by node/add. I suggest not doing it because that would by-pass all the node access control implemented by Drupal.

#### Reference

- [Node access right](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/group/node_access/7)

Comment: hook_node_access() is called on node/add page too? My goal is to check if node/add url has additional GET parameter - a token.

Comment: Yes, it is. In that case, the `$op` parameter is equal to `'create'`.